# In Android is there a way to view/change the cell output power and frequency

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make an android app that allows the user to manually view/change the output power of the cell signal and possibly frequency bands. This will be for my own purposes in testing RF immunity near cell phones for my electronics designs.

A first step may be to at least display the cell output power and frequency in real-time.

Is there a specific Android Intent I can send to set the power, or System variable I can read/write?

Can I assume a certain output power dependent on `CellSignalStrength`?